# Why main() function is called at the end of the program in python?

Tags: python, program-entry-point

Lets consider the following piece of code in Python:

```
def main():
    abc()
def abc():
      .
      .
      .
     <statements....>
      .
      .
      .
main() 
#Why the above line of code is used in python???
```

Lets consider other programming languages like C, C++ or Java or may be an interpreted language like BASIC. In BASIC, the code goes like this:
*if the name of the module is module1 then*:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World")
    Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module
```

This is in vbnet.
No Main() is called.
*The above code is just for illustration.*
So why is `main()` called at the end of the program in Python?

Comment: example module has `Sub Main()` - so it also runs `main()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

Because the creator of Python decided that was the way to use the language.

---

### Details

Very simply put, it's a similar convention in those compiled languages you mentioned, like Visual Basic, C or C++ (or also Java, C#, and many other), that a program is started by launching the `Main()` function (with some variation, like in a module that is defined as the startup when you compile it).

So, basically, when you compile, in the binary .exe. **the compiler adds a call to this Main() function**, even if you haven't written it in your code.

Whereas in a Python program, it's simply the file itself that is run, line by line. There is no convention that any function would be called. Python is not a compiled program, not much happens "behind the scenes" (actually, not entirely true, some global variables are set by the interpreter Python.exe).

So, in your Python program, if there wasn't a line `main()` at the end, you would just have *defined* 2 functions abc and main, but nothing would be actually called and your program would stop after the definition, nothing inside the two functions would be executed.

In the end, it's just that Python language has a different rule than those languages you mentioned. It's by design of the language.

Of course, it's not "rnadom", this design is more "natural" depending on the type - compiled or interpreted - of the language. For instance, you have a similar behavior in JavaScript, there is no "main()" function either, a JavaScript code is also executed starting from the top, line by line, with potential functions defined in the main code.

(Simplified explanation, some special case may apply).

Comment: Is there anything like stacktrace here?

Comment: @googleuser I don't understand your question. What do you mean ?

Comment: PYthon has a stack trace, basically the "top level function" is the file itself. You can see it when you have an error.

Comment: Like https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*aj7wuuq_KYMxOS4m2HNlfg.png in this picture, you can see first main() is there then m1() is there then m2() is there, so if we will not call main() at the last then the file will run but it will not show any output.

Comment: Am I right? @Pac0

Comment: You could say that Python program is also "stack based", the actual sartup function is your whole code (again, it's a simplification). it starts at the first line of your example program. In your question, the startup python function starts by defining two "sub-functions" (abc and main), and then executes the sub-function "main". That's just the way python language works.

Comment: You are kind of right, but in the image linked, I don't see the actual python code. The image is the state of the stack at some point in the execution. Not sure if the "main" that is written here is an actual python function defined with `def main()`, or if it is some "simplification" of the global python program added by the author of the article. The global program has no explicit name.

Comment: As said, in python there's nothing special about the name `main`. But _some global variables are set by the interpreter_ and one of these, called `__name__` may take the value `__main__`. Apart from that particular  \_\_main\_\_, any other `main` is just by choice and could have been `foo` without breaking anything.

Comment: Yes, the comment above by @IgnatiusReilly is important to know when you have your program defined in several python files. Sometimes you want the python file to be just library module with some functions defined to be called in another file, and sometimes you want the same file to actually do something if you run it directly. This is why in many python program you might see something like "`if __name__ == "__main__": some_function_to_be_run()`" as the last line of the program.

Answer (score 2):

Its because you have to define the function **before** calling it in Python. If you call it before the definition, it may give you an error. A VB program launches the Main() function automatically inside the startup module.

The general rule in Python is that a function should be defined before its usage, which does not necessarily mean it needs to be higher in the code.

```
lol()
def lol():
   print("Hello")
```

Should not work, but if you try

```
def test():
   lol()
def lol():
   print("Hello")

test()
```

It works.

Comment: Is there anything stacktrace like thing here?

Comment: Yeah, it may give you a stacktrace error if you mean that

Comment: Like https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*aj7wuuq_KYMxOS4m2HNlfg.png in this picture, you can see first main() is there then m1() is there then m2() is there, so if we will not call main() at the last then the file will run but it will not show any output.

Comment: it does not give any error

Comment: Because it ignores the error. Try it with using `try:` and `except Exception as e: print(e)`